# database - Setting up laravel project (local) with database hosted in 000webhost

Tags: database, laravel, host

I have project on my local computer. I want to test my db online on 000webhost. I set ***.env*** file like this

[.env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsFao.jpg)

and I had error like this

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u76N.jpg)

thanks before

Comment: you need put url your hosting inside .env too connect db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is hosted on an external server / hosting service (e.g. `000webhost`) then your database `DB_HOST` in `.env` *won't* be "localhost", it would be something like this:

```
mysql#.000webhost.com
```

Where the `#` is number of the allocated database server for your site.

Typically, when you create a new database, they show the database access details, use those details.

Comment: after I set mysql1.000webhost.com , I had error localhost refused to connect.

Comment: Did you enter all the credentials from 000webhost into `.env`? not just the DB_HOST, but also DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME etc...? Also, try connecting to the db server using MySQL Workbench or something to verify the credentials are correct.

Comment: yap, I also set that things. Also I changed DB_PORT from 3306 to 21 but error seems like before.

Comment: Did you verify the credentials work using a mysql client like MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Actually, I think I found the reason why it's not working. See this post: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/connecting-to-a-000webhost-database-externally/71555/6 I believe connecting to the 00webhost db externally (i.e. from your local laravel app) is a feature supported in their premium service, not in free tier. So the only way to make your laravel app connect to the db (in free tier) is to upload the site files to their server and run it from their server.

Comment: I think that's the solution. Thanks.